# LINQ Query to get grouping based on range of calculated values

Tags: linq, grouping, range

I have a sql query that I use to get a distribution for measurements into multiple Bins:

```
SELECT FLOOR(Value / @Step) * @Step AS Bin,        
       COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM Measurements WHERE (StepId = @StepId) 
       GROUP BY Bin ORDER BY Bin
```

where
Value = value of measurements returned based on StepId (primary key in measurements table)
Step = actually the number of groups(Bins in distribution).

How can I use `LINQ` and create grouping based on dynamically created range of values.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
double step = 100;
var stepId = 1;

from m in context.Measurements 
where m.StepId == stepId;
let bin = (Math.Floor(c.Value / step)) * step
orderby bin
group m by bin into x
select new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() }
```

You can even omit the Floor function because the "/" operator on integers has the same function in SQL.